# Amazon EB git setup : AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE path must not have quotes

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was absolutely stuck on this for a few hours - why the eb-cli kept saying

"The file does not exist"

when I was entering the (for me) normal

C:> set AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE="C:\Users\user_name\rootkey.txt"

The file was there and this is normally a valid format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what worked was simply this :

C:> set AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=C:\Users\user_name\rootkey.txt

with no quotes !

Hope that will help someone, could have used it this morning...